# OCR in a SWF file. It is possible?

Tags: flash, ocr, text-extraction

I need to extract some text from an SWF file. It is possible? Are there any libraries that can do that?

If yes, in which programming languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like [SOThink SWF decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/) to extract the resources and source code inside a .swf. Your text will either be embedded inside images, drawn into the movie from strings stored (or generated from) inside the .swf, or loaded from external sources.